# Wasm enable experimental features

Tags: webassembly

How to enable experimental features in wasm? Specifically, how to use `--experimental-wasm-anyref` with `WebAssembly.instantiate` (Wasm-Js API)? The option is neither npm nor wat2wasm option, and `WebAssembly.instantiate` doesn't seem to take parameters as command-line options.

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable experimental features in node, you must supply them as a command line argument:

```
node --experimental-wasm-anyref index.js
```